# Eclipse C/C++ Debugging with GDB

Tags: c, eclipse, debugging, gdb

I am trying to debug an executable using the Eclipse **C/C++ Attach to Application** functionality for a compiled executable. I have imported a new **C/C++ Executable** project, selected the appropriate executable and configured the debugger to use a msys/mingw version of gdb.

When I try to run the debugger I get console output for gdb

```
GNU gdb (GDB) 7.12
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "i686-w64-mingw32".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.
For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word".
```

But then an error window pops up saying that **gdb.exe has stopped working**

What might I have misconfigured that is causing this?

Answer (score 0):

This was caused by the gdb.exe version. I installed version 7.6.1-1 using MinGW-get instead of using Msys and the 7.6.1-1 version worked with eclipse.